# How to make this query: one field update anyway, another field only update in some condition?

Tags: mysql

updaten some_table set one_field=xxx, another_field=(only update in condition, ex. large then zero then minus one).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a CASE to either update the field to a new value or to set the same value again depending on the value of the condition.

```
UPDATE some_table
SET one_field = 'xxx',
    another_field = CASE WHEN another_field > 0
                         THEN another_field - 1
                         ELSE another_field
                    END
```

For decrementing a number that is not allowed to go below zero you could use [GREATEST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest):

```
UPDATE some_table
SET one_field = 'xxx',
    another_field = GREATEST(0, another_field - 1)
```

Comment: the GREATEST function is exactly what i'm looking for. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
update sone_table set one_field=xxx, another_field=IF(another_field > 0, value ,  another_field)
```

Comment: hi, Bogdan, what's the diff with Mark Byers's answer?

Comment: I tend to not like `cases`. Also seems shorter to me :) PS: thank you haim, I forgot the last field when I submited the response!

Answer (score 0):

Use an IF/Then/Else in your procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateTable(IN VALUE1 INT, IN VALUE2 INT)
BEGIN 
 IF (VALUE2 > 0) 
  THEN 
    UPDATE SOME_TABLE SET ONE_FIELD=VALUE1, ANOTHER_FIELD=VALUE2;

  ELSE 
    UPDATE SOME_TABLE SET ONE_FIELD=VALUE1; 
 END IF; 
END|
```

Comment: Mark posted while I was composing. His answer would be more inline. The above example gives you more control over the conditionals. Either way works; but his is probably what you are looking for.